# Error when Pushing to GitHub

Tags: javascript, html, git, heroku, github

Any ideas how to solve the following error?  We're just trying to push to GitHub, not Heroku.  Thanks!!

```
remote: warning: File examples/test/data/-deployd.0 is 64.00 MB; this  is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: warning: File examples/users/data/-deployd.0 is 64.00 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large     File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: d4c72f75677cd04f1c50b4e7847aa61f
 remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
 remote: error: File examples/users/data/-deployd.1 is 128.00 MB; this     exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To https://github.com/H-Ingram/FindVolunteerships.com.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
 error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/H-Ingram/FindVolunteerships.com.git'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub rejects files [larger than 100Mb](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files/).

Git (and source control in general) shouldn't really be used to store large files like binarys. If you find you need to, consider using [Git Large File Storage](https://github.com/blog/1986-announcing-git-large-file-storage-lfs) or another distribution technique.